# Fit and calibrate data frame via factors

Tags: r

At first, I use RStudio.
I have a data frame (APD) and I would like to fit the w.r.t to the factor Serial_number. The fit is a lm fit. Then I would like to use this fit to do a calibration (calibrate() out of the investr-package).

Here is an example picture of my data:

[image: Data]

Here's the data: [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQOB1.png)

Currently I use following lines to fit via Serial_number:

```
Coefficients<- APD %>% 
  group_by(Serial_number) %>% 
  do(tidy(fit<- lm(log(log(Amplification)) ~ Voltage_transformed, .)))
```

But here, I cannot apply the calibrate()-function. Calibrate function needs an object, that inherits from "lm". And tidy only works for S3/S4-objects.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: Since you haven't provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/5619526), here's a way using the `mtcars` data set: `do.call('rbind', by(mtcars, mtcars$cyl, function(d) broom::tidy(lm(mpg ~ hp, data = d))))`. In this case `cyl` would be the grouping variable

Comment: Thanks a lot! Wasn't aware of this example. WIll add it later and try your advice.

Comment: @bouncyball I'm not able to apply a predict function within by.. can you please have a look?

Answer (score 1):

In your posted code, you're trying to `rbind` the *predicted values* from each model, not the coefficients. The function for coefficients is just `coefficients(object)`.

I would also suggest un-nesting your code, since that makes it hard to read and change later on. Here are two generalized functions (each make assumptions, so edit as needed):

```
lm_by_variable <- function(data_, formula_, byvar) {
  by(
    data_,
    data_[[byvar]],
    FUN      = lm,
    formula  = formula_,
    simplify = FALSE
  )
}


combine_coefficients <- function(fit_list) {
  all_coefficients <- lapply(fit_list, coefficients)
  do.call('rbind', all_coefficients)
}
```

`lm_by_variable(...)` should be pretty self-evident: group by `byvar`, use `lm` with the given formula on each subset, and don't simplify the result. Simplifying results is really only useful for interactive work. In a script, it's better to know exactly what will be returned. In this case, a list.

The next function, `combine_coefficients(...)` returns a `matrix` of the fitted coefficients. It assumes every fitted model in `fit_list` has the same terms. We could add logic to make it more robust, but that doesn't seem necessary in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid it's a bit over my head.. I even do not see by().